# Show image in notification iOS - Expo managed workflow

Tags: expo, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo-notifications

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging to send notifications to devices. There's no problem on Android; however, when I send a notification to an iOS device, everything but the image displays.

After some research, I found out that I need to enable the [Notification Service Extension](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/ios-notification-images) inside Xcode. This is not an option for me since I am using a managed workflow with EAS.

I then came across some references stating that I need a custom plugin to make this work. Has anyone solved this, or am I missing something?

Currently using Expo SDK 49...